# Using Google Cloud Tasks with an Emulator

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-tasks, grpc-node

I am attempting local development with Google Cloud Tasks.  I am able to enqueue a task to Google Cloud, but I'd like to use an emulator for local development.  I have found two:

- https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator
- https://pypi.org/project/gcloud-tasks-emulator/

I have the same issue with both.  Example code in both projects show using an `sslCreds` option:

```js
import { CloudTasksClient } from "@google-cloud/tasks"
import { credentials } from "@grpc/grpc-js"

const client = new CloudTasksClient({
  port: 8123,
  servicePath: 'localhost',
  sslCreds: credentials.createInsecure(),
});
```

When I used this, I receive the following error:

```
  /app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/tasks/build/src/v2/cloud_tasks_client.js:203
                  throw err;

                  ^

  

  TypeError: Channel credentials must be a ChannelCredentials object

      at new ChannelImplementation (/app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/tasks/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:86:19)

      at new Client (/app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/tasks/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:62:36)

      at new ServiceClientImpl (/app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/tasks/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:58:5)

      at GrpcClient.createStub (/app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/tasks/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:334:22)

      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I'm not sure why this happens because in their code, credentials.createInsecure() creates an instance of `InsecureChannelCredentialsImpl` which extends `ChannelCredentials`.  If I go into `channel-js` in the Google-Cloud/tasks module and comment out the thrown error, everything works.

I have seen in an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/462) that there can be an incompatibility between Google's grpc libraries in Google Cloud Tasks and grpc.  I have updated everything to the latest version and I have gone into Google Cloud Task module to find the current version of grpc and installed that specific version in my project, but I still get this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked is advice mentioned here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/462#issuecomment-750417668

> I fixed this by making sure that @grpc/grpc-js matched the exakt same version as google-gaxs dependency, which I found out by inspecting the yarn.lock file to be 1.1.8.

In my case it was 1.8.0 in package-lock.json. My initialization code is exactly the same:

```
import { credentials } from "@grpc/grpc-js";
        const client = new CloudTasksClient({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
          port: 8123,
          servicePath: 'localhost',
          sslCreds: credentials.createInsecure(),
        });
```

Good luck!